# What word might describe a position between progressive and reactionary

Tags: political-theory, terminology

My understanding of both terms is that they relate to one's tolerance of the status quo, with "progressive" meaning someone who wants to progress beyond the current status quo ("change"), and "reactionary" describing someone who wants to return to a previously existing status quo ("let's make America great again").

My question though, is what word is generally used to describe someone who simply wants to maintain the current status quo?

Comment: In specific terms, "reactionary" is the contrary position to "actionary", i.e., people who react instead of acting. Therefore, movements 'against' all sorts of 'innovatons' can be described as 'reactionary'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If the countervailing ideology to Progressivism is Conservatism, what is the countervailing ideology to Reactionary movements?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/56175/if-the-countervailing-ideology-to-progressivism-is-conservatism-what-is-the-cou) Specifically, [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/56205/28994) pretty much nails it.